# Android TextView to displays a number to two decimal places only through XML

Tags: android

I am populating a ListView using TextView as a row through SimpleCursorAdapter.The numbers in the TextView are displayed as say 8  or 2.6786 etc.I want them to be displayed as 8.00 or 2.67 etc.Can it be done through XML(like input Type method etc).Please suggest a wayout. 
The question is bit different as under:
The codes are:

```
     // THE DESIRED COLUMNS TO BE BOUND
columns = new String[] { slStock.KEY_SCRIPT, getColumnName(2),c.getColumnName(3)};
 // THE XML DEFINED VIEWS FOR EACH FIELD TO BE BOUND TO
to = new int[] { R.id.tvstockscrpt, R.id.tvqty ,R.id.tvstockrate};
// CREATE ADAPTER WITH CURSOR POINTING TO DESIRED DATA

SimpleCursorAdapter cursAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.rowstock,   c,columns, to); 

   lvstockdisplay.setAdapter(cursAdapter);
```

Here you will notice that the cursor c fetches data (from database query in background) and populates it in the ListView directly.The question is how can I format the cursor data for say the TextView whose id is(R.id.tvstockrate) and which is populated by c.getColumnNames(3).**At which point in the codes the format statement can be inserted.**

Answer (score 14):

What about formatting the text when you set it?

```
yourTextView.setText(String.format("%.2f", value));
```

Answer (score -3):

This could be your solution

```
yourTextView.setText(String.format("%.2f", value));
```